# dynamic href react material ui drawer

Tags: reactjs, href, material-ui

Hi I want to code a dynamic href basing on team member names using react material ui drawer. This is a part of the code:

```
const sideList = (
<List>
{['MemberA', 'MemberB', 'MemberC'].map((text, index) => (
<a href={text}>
<ListItem button>{text}</ListItem>
</a>
))}
</List>
);
```

When I'm on the home page, it works: clicking on MemberA (on Drawer list), I'm redirected to homepage.com/MemberA.
But when I'm on MemberA page and I click on MemberB (on Drawer list), I'm redirected to homepage.com/MemberA/MemberB, that doesn't exist.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try a leading slash:
`` href={`/${text}`} ``

Comment: Hi ,thank you for the quick reply, you solved my problem! Can you explain me the difference between <a href={text}> and href={`/${text}`}?

Comment: good to hear :-). First appends path to current location (think drilling into details), second resolves path from root of site (think different site section).